# PHP For Loop adding extra row at end of loop

Tags: php, wordpress, for-loop

Im pulling data from 2 different WordPress tables and looping through to get the appropreate data into a table row.

```
$tid = $_POST['pqrnum']; //get estimate number
$results = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM eqnum WHERE id='.$tid); //getting estimate data
$pArray = explode(',', $results[0]->pnum); //creating array of product numbers in estimate
$ptable = "<table>"; //create table
$presults = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM eparts'); //getting product data
$pres= count($presults); //products array count
for($l = 0; $l <=count($pArray); $l++){  //loop through each product in the array
    $item = $pArray[$l]; //getting item number start 0
    $titem = $item + 1; //adding 1 to $item without disturbing it because product array starts at 1
    for ($x = 1; $x <= $pres; $x++) { //looping through product array
       if($titem == $presults[$x-1]->id){ // if estimate item = product number
         $ptable .= "<tr><td>item num ". $titem ." presults id ".$presults[$x-1]->id." presults name ".$presults[$x-1]->name."</td></tr>";
       }
    }
}
$ptable .= "</table>";
```

not sure why, but it seems to be printing an extra row, in this particular example there should be 3 rows, however this is the response:

item num 1 presults id 1 presults name Back up Alarm

item num 10 presults id 10 presults name Oil Filter

item num 11 presults id 11 presults name Spark Plug

item num 1 presults id 1 presults name Back up Alarm

as you can see the first and last lines are the same, it should be just the top 3, not 4.
just trying to determine why the extra row, any help appreciated.

Comment: `count()` returns the number of items in the array, but you're starting counting at zero, so you want `<` and not `<=`. Textbook off-by-one bug. :)

Comment: Although not related to your problem, WordPress's wpdb class has helper methods to guard your code from injections. Based on what you've provided you could use `$wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT pnum FROM eqnum WHERE id=%d", $tid));` to safely get that single column value.

Comment: In general, I can't seem to see why you care about the loop index at all? For `$results` it is effectively arbitrary (although zero-based) since it is done on the fly, and all of your products have IDs anyway, so it shouldn't matter. You should actually be able to use a `foreach` as far as I can tell.

Comment: Further, you don't need to grab all of the products in your second query, you can just grab the ones related to your first query, which this code does along with some guarding: https://3v4l.org/YrObo

Comment: To expand on the comment from @ChrisHaas, if you have an indexed array and you do need the index, you might find that doing something like `foreach ($items as $index => $item) { ... }` is less prone to error. (And doesn't incur the overhead of calling `count()` on each iteration.)

Answer (score 0):

Alex had the answer using < rather than <=, I thought I had tried that before but prefect thank you.